# Meaning of "breakers close beneath her lee" in Byron's Don Juan

Tags: meaning-in-context, poetry

From Byron's *Don Juan*, Canto II:

> Some lash'd them in their hammocks; some put on
>        Their best clothes, as if going to a fair;
>   Some cursed the day on which they saw the sun,
>        And gnash'd their teeth, and, howling, tore their hair;
>   And others went on as they had begun,
>        Getting the boats out, being well aware
>   That a tight boat will live in a rough sea,
>   Unless with **breakers close beneath her lee**.

In my understanding, the meaning here is "with breakers that are just below the gunwale (top edge) of the lee side of the boat". Am I right?

What puzzles me is that breakers (a kind of wave), thinking logically, should appear not leeward but windward of a boat.

Comment: A *breaker* is called that because it 'breaks' against rocks or the shore or against some obstacle immediately below the surface of the water. Breakers are therefore a sign that there is something against which the ship, too, can 'break' in a quite literal sense; and if the breakers are *close beneath her lee* the danger is near at hand and the ship is being driven toward it by the wind.

Comment: Breakers are a feature of a shoaling bottom, such as a reef or a beach. If they are immediately alee, you can't get away. Those boats barely went to windward in fine conditions, once trapped in breakers, they were doomed to have their bottoms pounded out.

Comment: @StoneyB - ah, I see! I never thought of that.